# Responsive Arrow Text in Recharts Donut Chart react js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

`I'm working on a React project where I'm using Re-charts to create a donuts chart. I have a custom label that I want to display as an arrow pointing to a specific section of the chart. The label(text and its above the arrow) should be responsive and adjust its size based on the chart's dimensions. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react';

import {
  ResponsiveContainer,
  PieChart,
  Pie,
  Tooltip,
  Cell,
  Legend,
  Sector,
} from 'recharts';

const data = [
  { name: 'Group A', value: 400 },
  { name: 'Group B', value: 300 },
  { name: 'Group C', value: 300 },
  { name: 'Group D', value: 200 },
];
const COLORS = ['#0088FE', '#00C49F', '#FFBB28', '#FF8042'];
const myStyles = {
  fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
  textAlign: 'center',
};

const mystyle = {
  gridContainer: {
    width: '100vw',
    height: '100vh',
  }
};


const renderActiveShape = (props: any) => {
  const RADIAN = Math.PI / 180;
  const {
    cx,
    cy,
    midAngle,
    innerRadius,
    outerRadius,
    startAngle,
    endAngle,
    fill,
    payload,
    percent,
    value
  } = props;
  const sin = Math.sin(-RADIAN * midAngle);
  const cos = Math.cos(-RADIAN * midAngle);
  const sx = cx + (outerRadius + 5) * cos;
  const sy = cy + (outerRadius + 5) * sin;
  const mx = cx + (outerRadius + 10) * cos;
  const my = cy + (outerRadius + 18) * sin;
  const ex = mx + (cos >= 0 ? 1 : -1) * 20;
  const ey = my;
  const textAnchor = cos >= 0 ? "start" : "end";
  const myCustomText = "abc"



  return (
    <g>
      <text className="heavy" x={cx} y={cy} dy={8} textAnchor="middle" fill={fill}>
        {myCustomText}
      </text>
      <Sector
        cx={cx}
        cy={cy}
        innerRadius={innerRadius}
        outerRadius={outerRadius}
        startAngle={startAngle}
        endAngle={endAngle}
        fill={fill}
      />

      <path
        d={`M${sx},${sy}L${mx},${my}L${ex},${ey}`}
        stroke={fill}
        fill="none"

      />
      <circle cx={ex} cy={ey} r={2} fill={fill} stroke="none" />
      <text className="recharts-text recharts-label"
        x={ex + (cos >= 0 ? 1 : -1) * 12}
        y={ey}

        textAnchor={textAnchor}
        fill="#999"
        dominantBaseline="central"
      //  fontSize={fontSize}

      >
        <tspan alignmentBaseline="middle">Del 400</tspan>


      </text>
      {/* <text
          //style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}
          x={ex + (cos >= 0 ? 1 : -1) * 12}
          y={ey}
          textAnchor={textAnchor}
          fill="#333"
        >{`PV ${value}`}</text> */}

    </g>
  );
};
const OrderAcceptedChart = () => {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
  const onPieEnter = useCallback(
    (_: any, index: any) => {
      setActiveIndex(index);
    },
    [setActiveIndex]
  )

  return (
    <div className="chart rating">
      <div className="cardInner">
        <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={400}>
          <PieChart style={myStyles}>
            <Pie
              activeIndex={activeIndex}
              activeShape={renderActiveShape}
              inactiveShape={renderActiveShape}
              data={data}
              dataKey="value"
              nameKey="name"
              cx="50%"
              cy="50%"
              innerRadius={60}
              outerRadius={80}
              fill="#8884d8"
              paddingAngle={5}
              labelLine={false}
            // label
            // cornerRadius={40}
            >
              {data.map((entry, index) => (
                <Cell key={`cell-${index}`} fill={COLORS[index % COLORS.length]} />
              ))}
            </Pie>
            <Tooltip />
            <Legend />
          </PieChart>
        </ResponsiveContainer>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
};

export default OrderAcceptedChart;
```

Share image:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FIzq.png